# click on a button with JQuery

Tags: java, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

There is somthing wrong with the page I want to test.

My first try:
When I clicked manually on a button, then I will be forwarded normally on the next page.
When I tried to click on the same button with selenium, then I get an error page "Sorry...something gone wrong...blabla". I think this problem can only solve the developer team of the page.

```
By book = By.cssSelector("#button\\.buchung\\.continue");
//By book = By.cssSelector("button.buchung.continue");
//By book = By.xpath("//*[@id='button.buchung.continue']");
WebElement element= ConfigClass.driver.findElement(book);
element.click();
```

But I want to try a workaround:

I clicked on the same button with JQuery.
I opened my chrome console and execute the button with:

```
jQuery('#button\\.buchung\\.continue').click()
```

**How can I execute this JQuery expression in my selenium code?**

I tried this, but without success:

```
JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
je.executeScript("jQuery('#button\\.buchung\\.continue').click()");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$`

```
je.executeScript("$('#button\\.buchung\\.continue').click()");
```

Comment: Nothing happens when I execute it.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery("selector") will return you a list.
I think you have to call click() on the element at index 0 (Assuming exactly one element satisfies the selector)

Code:

```
je.executeScript("jQuery('#button\\.buchung\\.continue')[0].click()");
```

Comment: When I execute it in my chrome cosole, then I get the next page. But in my selenium code nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close. If the *cssSelector* is uniquely identifying the *WebElement* you can use the following code block :

```
By book = By.cssSelector("#button\\.buchung\\.continue");
WebElement element= ConfigClass.driver.findElement(book);
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: Nothing happens. I dont get an error message. 
It is like the code finds something and tries to click on it.

Comment: Can you share the relevant _HTML_?